# Run multiple conf files in Windows Logstash service

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elastic-stack, logstash-configuration

I have installed Logstash 7.1.0 as a service in Windows through NSSM.
I haven't provided any Arguments in NSSM.

And In the pipelines.yml,
I set different pipelines just by enabling

```
- pipeline.id: dataupdate
      path.config: "D:\logstash-7.1.0\logstash-7.1.0\bin\myupdate.conf"
 - pipeline.id: groklogs
      path.config: "D:\logstash-7.1.0\logstash-7.1.0\bin\logs.conf"
```

When I start the service, the conf files don't seem to be running.
I assumed that when you give no arguments in NSSM, the pipelines.yml will be directed to the execution.

What I need is to run multiple conf files in my logstash service without having any interruption.
If I run in cmd, it'll stop the moment I close cmd, I do not want that.
Here's the contents of the config files:

logs.conf:

```
input {
  beats {
    port => 5044
  }
}
filter {
    grok {
match => {"message" =>"\[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Severity}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Plugin}\]%{SPACE}\[%{DATA:Servername}\](?<short_message>(.|\r|\n)*)"}
    }
} 
output {
  elasticsearch {
    hosts => ["localhost:9200"]
    index => "groklogs"
}
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

myupdate.conf:

```
input {
    jdbc {
        jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://mydb:1433;databasename=db01;integratedSecurity=true"
        jdbc_driver_class =>  "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
    jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Program Files\sqljdbc_6.2\enu\mssql-jdbc-6.2.2.jre8.jar"
        jdbc_user => nil
        statement => "SELECT * from agedata WHERE updated_on > :sql_last_value  ORDER BY updated_on"
    use_column_value =>true
        tracking_column =>updated_on
        tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
    }
}
output {
          elasticsearch { hosts => ["localhost:9200"] 
        index => "thisisit"
        action => update
            document_id => "%{id}"
            doc_as_upsert =>true}
          stdout { codec => rubydebug }
       }
```

Please help me.

Comment: Try to use forward slashes in your path, like `"D:/logstash-7.1.0/logstash-7.1.0/bin/myupdate.conf"`

Comment: @leandrojmp, I tried it, not working, id o not see any data push in my ES

Comment: Update your question with your configs.

Comment: @leandrojmp please check, ive updated.